# A manga about an emotive android fighter girl with black hair

Tags: battle-angel-alita

I believe this manga is relatively old, probably from the '90s. I don't recall there being an anime adaptation of it.

At the beginning of the story, a man found the partially destroyed head of an android with the brain still intact. He used parts from other androids he had found to reconstruct her. Her first limbs were delicate and were decorated with flower designs, I think. If I remember correctly, they were destroyed when she took on a powerful android. The man used this android's parts to create strong, sturdy limbs for the android girl.

The girl was cheerful and very expressive despite being an android. She was probably in her "teens," had shoulder-length black hair and was drawn with large, emotive eyes. The man was older, and I think he was a scientist or researcher, as well as a fighter. The other androids that appeared were drawn in great detail, and I think there was some detailed gore.

The last thing I remember is that they were in a bar, and there was a giant android head/snake-like thing that was attacking them.

Comment: how old is: relatively old? Can you remember details about the drawing style? Any detail can help ;)

Comment: Yup, this sounds *exactly* like *Battle Angel Alita*, aka *Gunnm*.

Comment: FYI, there was an anime, from 1993: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0107061/  One of the first I watched after Akira.

Answer (score 11):

Perhaps you're looking for [*Battle Angel Alita/Gunnm*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_Angel_Alita)

[image: From Chapter 1]

[image: Ibid]

> The series is set in the post-apocalyptic future and focuses on Alita, a cyborg who has lost all memories and is found in a garbage heap by a cybernetics doctor who rebuilds and takes care of her. She discovers that there is one thing she remembers, the legendary cyborg martial art Panzer Kunst, which leads to her becoming a Hunter Warrior or bounty hunter. The story traces Alita's attempts to rediscover her past and the characters whose lives she impacts on her journey.

Comment: Thanks so much! Battle Angel Alita is the series I was thinking of.